# Roblox Takes forever to open Up

Tags: roblox

For some reason, when I open the Roblox site, it takes 10 minutes or longer to finish loading. I've tried turning the wifi, restarting my computer, but it still doesn't work! When I open a game, it just loads forever and ever and ever!! I use an iOS/iMac. How do I get myself out of this???

Comment: Anything else you could tell us about your setup? Have you tried upgrading your computer?

Answer (score 1):

Roblox is down right now. It'll be back later today.

[DevForum thread on the topic](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/robloxcritical-platform-unuseable-for-some-users-over-the-last-2-hours/463675/3)

Update: This should now be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Their might be a few reasons but you have to specifically tell a reason, is it because you have other apps or tabs running, it can stress the ram, is it because their is a humongous update in the Roblox server, or you can try system defragging your PC, is it because you have to much data, apps, files and other junk?

Comment: Nevermind the solution is fixed